# How ast.literal_eval work on list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Does ast.literal_eval() work with list of dictionaries ? For me it is giving malformed string error ?

> [[u'ABN', u'12', u'', 2.69, u'222.222.222.222', u'253', u'ID99',
>   u'Savings', u'300', u'-120', u'Not Useful'], [u'DB', u'44', u'',
>   2.628, u'333.333.333.333', u'240', u'ID77', u'Savings', u'3371', u'-440', u'Not Useful']]

Comment: Can you show the string you're trying to eval?

Comment: I have updated the sample of data

Comment: Just so you know, your sample data is not a list of dictionaries.  It is a list of lists.

Comment: How are you giving the sample data to `literal_eval`?

Comment: it is in variable called values and I am doing values  = ast.literal_eval(values).

Answer (score 3):

> Does ast.literal_eval() work with list of dictionaries?

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = """[{'x': 1}, {'y': 2}]"""
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[{'x': 1}, {'y': 2}]
```

Yes.

And, for what it's worth, you sample data (which is a list of lists) works for me as well:

```
>>> s = """[[u'ABN', u'12', u'', 2.69, u'222.222.222.222', u'253', u'ID99', u'Savings', u'300', u'-120', u'Not Useful'], [u'DB', u'44', u'', 2.628, u'333.333.333.333', u'240', u'ID77', u'Savings', u'3371', u'-440', u'Not Useful']]"""
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[[u'ABN', u'12', u'', 2.69, u'222.222.222.222', u'253', u'ID99', u'Savings', u'300', u'-120', u'Not Useful'], [u'DB', u'44', u'', 2.628, u'333.333.333.333', u'240', u'ID77', u'Savings', u'3371', u'-440', u'Not Useful']]
```

Comment: Based on sample data I have posted, should I convert the string representation into list of dictionary before inputting data into ast?

Comment: Not Sure how is it working for you ? Probably you are assigning to string that is why it is working not directly.